# Disconnect a solution from Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

What is the easiest way to disconnect a solution from Visual Studio Online?

I can't see any options in the menus or in the Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MrHinsh is correct, and here are the steps to do this in VS 2015.

In Team Explorer, click on Settings. This displays a little treeview, with top node "Git".

Click Repository Settings

At the bottom of the Repository Settings screen, there is a section for Remotes, where you can edit which Remote you are connected too.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, select the solution in the solution explorer, then go to the **File--Source Control--Advanced--Change Source Control**, unbind your solution.

Comment: That's the usual place in the menus in VS, and it's usually very easy, but it is not there in my Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Comment: Do you use Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Git then you do not need to do anything.

You can update the Origin to your new location, or safely leave Git and use it offline.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Use "Git remote"...

Comment: thanks. I did eventually figure that out in Visual Studio, but if was not obvious!